# Excel VBA Writing Multiple Scenario Using If Conditional Statement

Tags: excel, vba

```
wk2LastRow = wk2.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

i = 2

For wk2Range = 2 To wk2LastRow

id = wk2.Cells(wk2Range, 1)

Set f = wk1.Range("A2:I7").Find(id, , xlValues, xlPart)
    'Conditional Statement code to be inserted here

Next wk2Range
```

Background information:

- Search values are in Worksheet 2 (wk2).
- wk2Range selects the entire search value
- "A2:I7" are the values below from **1 to 6**

I want to match a list of values to the "A2:I7" (1 to 6). The data that I need from the table is the **second OFF day's Date**. For example, For name 2, the second off day dates are 01/02/15, 01/06/15.

> I want the code to find a match, afterwards read the code horizontally to find the second off day, and then end(xlup) to get the date.

I have thought of the 4 possible scenarios but am unsure of how to write them down into code. I just need the second off days date, the code can ignore the rest of the variations.

- On On Off Off
- On Off Off On
- Off Off On On
- Off On On Off

Please see picture for elaboration:

[image: Excel On Off Picture]

Comment: I inserted your picture, but am still unsure what you are trying to do. Please modify your question to explain clearer.

Comment: @LanceRoberts Thank you for adding the picture. I hope the edit clarifies the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not the most elegant solution but should return the dates you are hoping for:

```
Private Sub ViewHolidayDates()

'Defined rota range:
Set Rota = Sheet1.Range("B2:I7").Cells

'How many dates across.
Dim RowLength As Integer: RowLength = 8

'Which Name we are looping.
Dim Row As Integer: Row = 1

'Where within the range loop we are.
Dim UserRecord As Integer: UserRecord = 0

'Current count of "off" for current Row.
Dim Holiday As Integer: Holiday = 0
Dim DateValue As String

For Each Record In Rota

If Record = "off" Then

Holiday = Holiday + 1

If Holiday = 2 Then

    DateValue = Sheet1.Range("B2").Offset(-1, UserRecord).Value

    MsgBox (DateValue)

    'reset Holiday counter:
    Holiday = 0

End If

End If

UserRecord = UserRecord + 1

If UserRecord = RowLength Then
    'Reset counters ready for new "Name"
    Row = Row + 1
    UserRecord = 0
    Holiday = 0
End If

Next Record

End Sub
```

Please set the `Rota` variable in my code to the range in your Excel Sheet and also the `Sheet1.Range("B2")` in my code to be the first record in your range.

**UPDATE:**

You can adjust the `RowLength` and the `If Holiday = 2` to values more suited to your scenario. You should also note `"off"` is case sensitive.

**UPDATE**

I have updated the `Holiday` counter to reset within the `IF` statement, this will then return a date for each instance of the second "off".

Also, my `Row - Row - 1` was  not required, as the range I defined was fixed: `Sheet1.Range("B2")` we need only to say `Offset(-1, UserRecord)` and dynamically pass in how many columns across we expect the date to be.

Comment: Could you please explain `DateValue = Sheet1.Range("B2").Offset(Row - Row - 1, UserRecord).Value`? What does the `Row - Row - 1` means? Thanks for the response!

Comment: The code works in identifying the first **second day off** for each Name that we are looping. Is it possible to loop through until the end of the row before moving on to the next name? Thank you so much for helping! I am learning a lot from your code :)

Comment: In my example, "B2" is the data reference point, from here we use the loop variables to work out how many columns across we are (UserRecord), then how many rows up we need to go to grab the date (Row - Row - 1). A dynamic way of navigating to the date once we have found the second "off".

Comment: Hey, yes the code does actually loop through the entire data set. Is there something specific you need to extract?

Comment: I want to extract all the second off dates in each row. For the offset( row - row - 1 ), does the " - " means subtract? How does that offset work step by step?

Comment: Ah, okay easily done. I shall update my code for you.

Comment: @Kelvinlimjk I have updated my code. If this answers your question sufficiently you can mark mine or the other answer with a tick for completeness.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't realise the tick was for completion. Your code works! What if I want to find the second consecutive off?

Comment: `Dim Holiday As Integer: Holiday = 0` Is it best practice to assign values to the variable in this manner?

Comment: In most languages you define and assign to variables immediate, this is just the VBA way to do this. I find it a little neater but it's not essential you follow this practice.

Comment: Using your Visual Basic Editor, press 'F8' on your keyboard to step through a routine, you can then hover your cursor over the variables as the code steps through, this should help you understand the code and make tweaks to suit your needs such as any scenario of 'holiday' count you need in this example!

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it, just assign SecondOff to the range of your choice in the calling sub. Note that there are probably better ways to do it than with Find, but I wanted to stay in sync with your question.

```
Public Function SecondOff(Schedule As Range) As Variant

Dim rw As Range, Temp As Variant
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim wrow As Integer, firstI As Integer, origI As Integer    
ReDim Temp(1 To 6, 1 To 9)

For Each rw In Schedule.Range("2:" & Schedule.Rows.Count).Rows

  i = 1
  j = 2
  wrow = rw.Cells(1, 1)
  Temp(wrow, 1) = wrow
  If (rw.Find("off", rw.Cells(1, i), xlValues, xlPart) Is Nothing) Then
    Temp(wrow, 2) = "None"
  Else
    origI = rw.Find("off", rw.Cells(1, i), xlValues, xlPart).Column
    Do
      firstI = rw.Find("off", rw.Cells(1, i), xlValues, xlPart).Column
      If firstI <= origI And j > 2 Then Exit Do
      i = rw.Find("off", rw.Cells(1, firstI), xlValues, xlPart).Column
      If i <= origI Then Exit Do
      If i - firstI = 1 Then
        Temp(wrow, j) = Schedule(1, i)
        j = j + 1
      Else
        i = firstI
      End If
    Loop Until j > 8
  End If    
Next rw

SecondOff = Temp

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Sir for answering the question. Could you please provide some comment explanation to the code? I hope to understand and learn the code. I thought `find` method is faster than `loop`. Is it true? What other methods are there?

Comment: Find may or may not be faster than a loop, that would have to be tested.  The real problem with find is that after it goes though the searched range it loops back through, so I had to put in a lot of excess code to cover that.  My code is just a simple loop, covering one row at a time.  It saves the first off value found, for testing about that loopback condition.  It then keeps finding the next 'off', constantly checking for the loopback condition, then assigning it to a variant answer array.  At the end, the answer array is assigned to a range.